# How to Make a PDF 'Look' Uniform?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normally-distributed random variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$: $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Let $Y$ be a mapping from $X$ onto the interval $(0,1)$ using the sigmoid function: $Y=\text{sig}(X)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-X}}$.

It can be shown that $Y$ has the following probability density function:

$
f_Y (y) = \frac{1}{y(1-y)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp{\left(-\frac{\left(\ln\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}
$

My question is: for what value of $\sigma$ is $f_y (y)$ **the flattest**? (i.e., is the most similar to a uniform distribution over $(0,1)$).

Is a closed-form solution to this problem possible?

PS: I am leaving the definition of "the flattest" open, because I am OK with any one that makes sense. For instance, a simple one could be the one that minimizes the integral of $\left[f_Y(y)-1\right]^2$ over $(0,1)$.

Comment: There's a great answer for this... I'm typing it up, bu it might take a minute!

Comment: @Arkamis Looking forward to it.

Comment: I don't really understand @Arkamis's answer, but visually $\sigma=1$ seems to be a suboptimal choice compared to $\sigma=\sqrt2$ (from $f_Y''(1/2)=0$), or to $\sigma=2\sqrt{2/\pi}\approx1.6$ (from $f_Y(1/2)=1$, also close to fedja's answer): http://i.stack.imgur.com/oBGze.png

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes, I neglected to account for the fact that the coefficients I calculated were for a scaled version of the Hermite polynomials. Naively, that would suggest $\sigma = \sqrt{2}/2$, but we can probably improve on that, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the Taylor series expansion for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$:

$$f(x) \approx \frac12 + \frac{x}{4} - \frac{x^3}{48} + \frac{x^5}{480} + \cdots.$$

We see that aside from the constant term, only odd terms are in the expansion.

Now, let's look at the Wiener-Askey polynomial chaos representation of a uniform random variable using a standard normal random variable.

Let $z \sim U(0,1)$ and $\zeta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Gaussian random variables belong to the Gauss-Hermite polynomial chaos. Let $\Phi_i(\zeta)$ represent the $i$th Hermite polynomial.

Then, we can say that

$$z = \sum_{i=0}^\infty z_i\Phi_i(\zeta).$$

The $z_i$ coefficients are *deterministic*, we can compute them using the Galerkin method

$$z_i = \frac{\left\langle z\Phi_i(\zeta)\right\rangle}{\left\langle \Phi_i^2\right\rangle} = \frac{1}{\left\langle\Phi_i^2\right\rangle} \int_{-\infty}^\infty z\Phi_i(\zeta) w(\zeta) d\zeta$$
where $w(\zeta)$ is the weighting function that comes from orthogonality of the polynomials. Of course, for the Hermite polynomials, the weighting function is (to within a scaling of the independent variable) the normal distribution PDF!

The presence of $z$ in the integrand is problematic, but we can get rid of it by casting $\zeta$ and $z$ to a uniform random variable $u$ using an inverse sample transform. I'll spare the details, unless you want, but in the end we get a series of coefficients.

As it turns out, when $i$ is even and greater than zero, the resulting integrand is an odd function! Therefore, we're left with a series of coefficients, and a unity term.

This unity term, when $i=0$, always represents the mean of the variable. Since the mean of $z$ is 0.5, then we expect that $z_0 = 0.5$.

---

Now, notice the Taylor expansion. The $x^0$ coefficient is 0.5, the $x^1$ coefficient is 0.25, etc.

Now, here are the coefficients for the Gauss-Hermite representation of a uniform distribution:

$$\{ 0.5, .282, 0, -0.0576, 0, 0.01934, \ldots\}.$$

(Note: these coefficients are for scaled Hermite polynomials such that $\langle \Phi_i\Phi_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}.$)

These are the coefficients of the *polynomials*, but if you sub them in, you will get something quite close to what shows up in the Taylor expansion.

The more terms you take in the truncated polynomial chaos expansion, the flatter you get. At about 12 terms, the result is almost perfectly uniform. So, $\sigma \sim \sqrt{2}/2$ seems like a pretty good choice!

Comment: This looks like a great answer, although it will probably take me some time to understand it. I will mark it as correct anyway. Can I be a bit cheeky and ask what would change in the above answer if we changed $Y=2\text{sig}(x) - 1$ such that now $Y\in(-1,1)$. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually running some computations to see if I can pick a better $\sigma$, but I haven't touched this code in forever. As for your last question, once you have something as a uniform RV, it's a simple linear transform to change it to any other normal distribution. So, pragmatically, just do that. If you wanted to go from [-1,1] directly, you could do that, too; it would just change your parameters in the integral. I can run it real quick to see what I get.

Comment: @MGA I have to leave for the day, but I will think on this tonight and see if I can give you a better response with some results. Polynomial Chaos is not a widely-appreciated tool in mathematics, but it is impossible to ignore the links between the Gauss-Hermite representation of the uniform distribution and the Taylor series of the sigmoid function.

Comment: @Arkamis: $\sqrt{2}/2$ looks far too small.  Did you mean its reciprocal?

Comment: @Henry ... Yes. Long day >.<

Answer (score 3):

Since the standard deviation of a standard logistic distribution is $\pi/\sqrt{3} \approx  1.8138$, I would have guessed that it would have been a good answer.

But empirically something like $\sigma=1.6638$ seems to produce a cumulative distribution function close to that of a uniform distribution on the unit interval. Here "close" is the integral of the square of the vertical gap.

In the following graph, the green line uses $\sigma=\pi/\sqrt{3}$ and the blueline uses $\sigma=1.6638$, while the red line is straight, i.e. the cumulative distribution function of a uniform distribution on the unit interval.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another "reasonable" approach. 
Since the median and the mean are fine automatically, let's agree some other parameter, say, the 25% percentile. We should have $P(X>\log 3)=\frac 14$ whence $P(Z>\frac{\log 3}{\sigma})=\frac 14$ where $Z$ is the standard normal. Now, looking at the Normal Distribution tables, we get $\sigma\approx 1.6$. It doesn't look too bad on the graph and I doubt that any higher precision makes much sense without an exact definition of flatness...